# Add custom metadata to Subversion

Tags: svn

How can we add/update custom metadata to subversion branches?

e.g. metadata would be "July-3-2012" . The date indicates when branch should be merged to trunk

Answer (score 4):

You can use `svn propset mergedate July-3-2012 dir` to set a property named `mergedate` to the desired value on the directory `dir`.

See more info in [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html)

What this actually means is that you can [set custom properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html)** to any file/folder in trunk or in a branch. This comes in very handy in a lot of cases. Although I am not sure if you can detect a branch operation you could also try to automate this process with [hook scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) - they are very powerful and can do a lot of the work for you.

** - Search for "Custom revision properties are" in the page as there is no anchor link to the exact content I wanted to share with you.